# Reading Json file from local ftp server

Tags: json, parsing

I am a json file named File1.js stored in my local server. I want to read the json file contents and want to display the data in an other file. I have tried with javascript coding but it not working fine.

Below coding for my sample json file. Please help me with the coding to write the data to another file. Can I use php to parse the data and display or can i continue with javascript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON Sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <script src="ftp://devapp@ftp.appdevelopmentindia.in/www/new.js"></script>
    <script>
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
      var output="<ul>";
      for (var i in data.users) {
        output+="<li>" + data.users[i].firstName + " " + data.users[i].lastName + "--"       
         + data.users[i].joined.month+"</li>";
      }

      output+="</ul>";
      document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
    });
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is your data.json file in same directory as this html file?

Comment: ya i have it in the same directory .But the contents are not getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

If this is your full HTML then it might be because you have not included jquery.js file.

Comment: ya i have that jquery.js file ..Can we have a differnent method to do it

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you did some mistake in for loop. You are using for i in data.users, actually you should say, i in data.users.length.
Try this code:

```
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
      var output="<ul>";
      for (var i=0; i < data.users.length; i++ ) {
        output+="<li>" + data.users[i].firstName + " " + data.users[i].lastName + "--"       
         + data.users[i].joined.month+"</li>";
      }

      output+="</ul>";
      document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
    });
```